# Is it possible connect a Raspberry Pi Pico W to an EDUROAM Wifi (WPA2 authentication)?

Tags: wifi, wpa, micropython, pi-pico-w

Could someone help me? I'm a student at a university, and I'm trying to connect my Raspberry Pi Pico W to the Eduroam Wi-Fi using micropython code, but I'm having trouble. Is it better to use ESP32 to connect to the Eduroam network?

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/144496/157074

Comment: Welcome to RPi SE. FWIW, some here (myself included) will struggle to understand what "Eduroam" implies. You could do yourself a favor by including a brief synopsis of it in your Q.